# Twitter & Identi.ca-In-One Add-on for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, twitter, ident.ca

Is there an add-on around that allows me to log into my twitter AND identi.ca account simulateously?

I'm tired of having IdentiFox and Echofon (formerly Twitterfox) running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Ubiquity command](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Ubiquity/Commands_In_The_Wild) for firefox, and add commands for twitter and identica. A twitter command comes with Ubiquity, though alternative versions with differing features are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FireStatus for that purpose, IT supports identi.ca, twitter, facebook

You can get FireStatus here http://code.google.com/p/firestatus/

Comment: Does it support displaying tweets from followed users?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way left is to make a new add-on which asks you which kind of account you want to login. Probably a restriction can be only 1 of the two at the same time, just like EchoFon.

I would like to make one as both Twitter and Identi.ca use the same API.
Till now to my knowledge there is no such addon.

Comment: Bah, this sucks! FML... :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try a desktop client. i'm sure there is one for your OS.
and that way, you can just close firefox sometimes.